# Computational complexity sparse outer product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus, computational-complexity, computational-mathematics

Suppose that I have a matrix $A$ of dimension $m \times m$, which can be computed as:

$$A= X D X^\top$$

where $X$ is a matrix of dimension $m \times n$, with $m > n$, and $D= \operatorname{diag}(d)$, with $d$ a vector $n \times 1$. I want to compute the computational complexity of creating matrix $A$. Because I can write matrix $A$ as the sum of outer products as:

$$A= \sum_{i=1}^n d_i x_i x_i^\top $$
where $x_i$ is the $i$th column of $X$. Since I am performing $n$ outer products of vectors with dimensions $m$, the overall computational complexity is $\mathcal{O}(mn)$.

Suppose now that each $x_i$ is a sparse vector, with only $n$ non-zero entries. Can I conclude that the computational complexity is $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$? I am having $n$ outer products of vectors whose dimension is $m \times 1$, but only $n$ entries are non zero.

Comment: For the original computation: computing $A$ requires adding $n$ matrices of size $n \times n$; doesn't this bring the complexity up to $n^3$?

Comment: Adding $n$ matrices of size $m \times m$. I was not considering the cost of addiction. So the cost should be $\mathcal{O}(mn)$ to compute the $n$ outer products, plus $\mathcal{O}(m^2n)$ to compute the sum of the $n$ rank-1 matrices of dimension $m \times m$?

Comment: I think so, so in other words that’s $O(m^2n)$ overall